# Ajax HTML FORM not sending input

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, forms

i've got a problem I can't figure out.

I have a page (index.php) that open a form, includes another page with PHP (indexsearch.php) and close the form. 
This included page is working with a script that display some datas from my website, the data are requested on the page with an AJAX function that is linked to search.php, that is working with a table and checkboxes so we can choose which data to work with. 
See this schema :

[image]

Everything is working fine but the checkboxes are not send even when they are checked. I did added the name and the value in search.php

```
<td> <input type="checkbox" name="ajout[]" value="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>"/> </td>
```

I also did not opened another form. 
So I guess the problem may come from the fact the AJAX datas work as an independant form that is not included in my page.

Please see the html code :

```
<body>
<div class="division">
                    <table id="text-p">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                        <form action="" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <textarea id="text-p1" name="text-p1" maxlength="300" placeholder="Text1"></textarea>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <textarea id="text-p2" name="text-p2" maxlength="300" placeholder="Text2"></textarea>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000">
                            Logo : <input name="logo-p1" type="file" accept="image/*">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000">
                            Logo : <input name="logo-p2" type="file" accept="image/*">
                            </td>
                        </tr>

              </table>
                </div>


                <div class="division">

        <div width="100%" style="height: 50px;">
            <input type="text" name="recherche" id="recherche" style="width: 75%; float:left; display: inline-block;" placeholder="Rechercher...">
            <div style="float:right;">
                    <input type="radio" name="onglet" value="val1" id="act" checked="">Activité
                    <input type="radio" name="onglet" value="val2" id="sect">Secteur
                    <input type="radio" name="onglet" value="val3" id="ecr">Ecrans
            </div>
        </div>
        <div width="100%" id="resultats">


                    <input id="ok" type="button" class="pageselector" name="pageselector" value="1" checked=""><table id="resultat1" width="100%" style="text-align: center;" class="resultatshow">
                <tbody><tr>
                        <td>Cat</td>
                                            <td>Text-1</td>
                        <td>Text-2</td>
                        <td>Sélec</td>

                </tr>
                        <tr>

                        <td>Cat1</td>
                                                <td>NULL</td>
                        <td>NULL</td>
                        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="ajout[]" value="1"> </td>
            </tr>

                    <tr>

                        <td>CAT2</td>
                                                <td>EMPTY</td>
                        <td>EMPTY</td>
                        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="ajout[]" value="2"> </td>
            </tr>

</table></div>                      
                    <input type="submit" value="UPDATE">

                </div>


            </body>
```

How can I fix that ?

Comment: perhaps an example of the HTML as it appears in your browser (not the PHP version) would help in asking your question

Comment: Can you check, how are u reading the values of checkbox in your script. is the name/Id is same as the one in view source of HTML. Also if this is form with in form, plz check if u want to use "fome1.form2.id" to locate the element?

Comment: @JaromandaX I added an example of what my html look like.

Comment: @Aarati There is no problem with the script actually, please have a look at the HTML example I added. I think it comes from syntaxes outside of the script

Comment: You need to provide an [mcve] (emphasis on the minimal) **in the question itself** (a link to a third party site does not count as *in the question*)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Use [a validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/). Your form doesn't even have a submit button in it, so I don't understand how you are submitting it. You mentioned Ajax, but there's no JS in the question.

Comment: @Ezhno use totalvalidator.com to check your html code. There some mistakes in yours.

Comment: @Quentin I removed the JS for the minimal example. And there is a submit button : `<input type="submit" value="UPDATE">`

Comment: @Ezhno — The submit button is not inside the form. See my previous note about using a validator.

Comment: I think i know what your problem is. Perhaps the checkboxes are unchecked? If so, know that when the checkbox is unchecked in HTML the field will NOT BE SENT. So you need to check if the field is not present in POST, it means it is unchecked, therefore you need to save false state.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but I guess it can be caused by square brackets in the `name` attribute of your checkboxes. If you have reason to do it, you have to work with it properly. For example, here is the HTML form field:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[myOption]'>
```

You have to remember that `POST` is an array of options. So doing like above you have to access it in the right way on the server side:

```
$_POST['checkbox']['myOption'];
```

I don't know if that solves your problem but I hope it helps a little bit

Comment: Downvoter- could you please tell me what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: Thank you for your kind help Sebastian, I indeed know that the [] refer to an array, and that I must access it in the correct way :) The problem is in front, not in back (My checkboxes values are not sent)